# Does card.io extract name on the card and Account number/card number?

Tags: android, card.io

Is there any possibility to extract particular details from the card like name on the card and account number which is at the bottom of the card?

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible with card.io. Here is the Javadoc for the CreditCard class and you can see that it is not possible to extract other information than card number, CVV, expiry month and year and postal code. http://card-io.github.io/card.io-Android-SDK/io/card/payment/CreditCard.html